# How to find out the index that caused a ConstraintError when calling add or put in IndexedDB?

Tags: indexeddb

Whenever a index is created with `unique=true`, a `ConstraintError` can be returned when calling add or put.

The error that can be read from `IDBReaquest.error` is a `DOMException` which does not have information enough. Here is what Chrome returns:

```
{name:'ConstraintError', message: 'Unable to add key to index 'country-city': at least one key does not satisfy the uniqueness requirements.'}
```

, and Firefox:

```
{name:'ConstraintError', message: 'A mutation operation in the transaction failed because a constraint was not satisfied.'}
```

Clearly the browser knows the index that caused the error.

But does anyone knows any way to find it out?